# How to further optimize this algorithm for detecting motion between two images using AVX2

Tags: c, simd, avx, avx2

I have written an algorithm that compares two image frames (represented as ARGB arrays with each color channel byte) and detect if there is a significant difference between the images, taking into account some noise. The two frames are called `previousFrame`and `currentFrame`. The total amount of pixels per frame is stored in `dataLength`.

The acceptable noise level for a specific R, G or B value of a pixel is based on the `previousFrame`'s value. These noise levels are stored in the `noiseLevels` array which has a length of 256 (one element for each possible color channel value) and the values in the array range from the usual 0-255.

In this algorithm, I compute the absolute difference for each pixel's color channel between the two frames and check if it exceeds the set noise level. If so, I do some arbitrary actions. The alpha channel may be ignored for this (as it's expected to always have a value of 255).

I already optimized the calculating of the absolute difference between the two frames with AVX2. My question is: **Can I further optimize this algorithm for fastest execution in ways I haven't thought of?** It may be assumed here that memory is not an issue. Is there a more efficient way of calculating the diff, or checking whether the diff exceeds the acceptable noise level?

A simplified snippet of the code:

```c
// AVX2 mm256 register holds 256 bits = 32 bytes = 8 int32 = 8 pixels
for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 8) {
  __m256i previousChunk = _mm256_loadu_si256(previousFrame);
  __m256i currentChunk = _mm256_loadu_si256(currentFrame);
  __m256i _absoluteDiff = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_subs_epu8(previousChunk, currentChunk), _mm256_subs_epu8(currentChunk, previousChunk));
  unsigned char* absoluteDiff = (unsigned char*) &_absoluteDiff;

  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    // Compare if R/G/B channels of current frame changed more than
    int signBits = (noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]] - absoluteDiff[1]) | (noiseLevels[previousFrame[2]] - absoluteDiff[2]) | (noiseLevels[previousFrame[3]] - absoluteDiff[3]);

    if (signBits < 0) {
      // Do some stuff
    }
    absoluteDiff += 4;
    previousFrame += 4;
  }

  currentFrame += 32;
}
```

**Edit 2023-06-09 (22:26 Amsterdam time)**

The section for determining whether a pixel changed significantly has been rewritten to the following as suggested by @WeatherVane. This yielded a minor performance improvement (I assume the compiler already optimized the original code quite well).

```c
bool isDifferent = (absoluteDiff[1] > noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]]) || (absoluteDiff[2] > noiseLevels[previousFrame[2]]) || (absoluteDiff[3] > noiseLevels[previousFrame[3]]);
absoluteDiff += 4;
previousFrame += 4;
```

**Edit 2023-06-09 23:20 amsterdam time**

Following up on a suggestion by @PeterCordes, I am now using the following method to determine whether or not there is a significant difference:

```c
int signBits = (noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]] - absoluteDiff[1]) | (noiseLevels[previousFrame[2]] - absoluteDiff[2]) | (noiseLevels[previousFrame[3]] - absoluteDiff[3]);

if (signBits < 0) {
  // Do some stuff
}
```

**Edit 2023-06-11 23:45 amsterdam time**

One huge optimization I found (as the frequency at which pixels change beyond the threshold) is to include the following check **before** going into the loop that iterates over each individual pixel's results:

```c
unsigned long long* absDifL = (unsigned long long*) absoluteDiff;

if (!(absDifL[0] || absDifL[1] || absDifL[2] || absDifL[3])) {
  continue;
}
```

This check determines if any of the 8 pixels changed without looking at specific color channels. It allows to very quickly ignore "uninteresting" parts of the new frame.

Sidenote: This is very specific whether or not this optimization actually helps, depending on how much noise there is on the raw images. As the noise increases, there will be less clusters of 8 pixels where the diff is 0.

Comment: Is this a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: One inefficiency is the multiple updating of `absoluteDiff` and `previousFrame`. If you don't increment them in the `if` statements that can be reduced to single update for each in their body.

Comment: @WeatherVane ah I wasn't aware of Code Review, sorry.

With regards to absoluteDiff++/previousFrame++: it is expected to happen frameWidth * frameHeight * 4 times. So a lot of times.

The previousFrame/currentFrame is laid out in the format [a,r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,b...]. With the absoluteDiff++/previousFrame++ statements I am effectively moving forward in those arrays.

Comment: I edited the last comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane Each if statement is adding one additional increment to the prior one. I dont think it is possible to reduce it to just a single increment?

Comment: You can by indexing the test instead of incrementing as a side-effect. So the second one would be `else if (absoluteDiff[1] > noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]])` which is cheaper than multiple writes to the pointer values.

Comment: Is "Do some stuff" amenable to SIMD implementation? The conditional nature of running that code only if some condition is true complicates matters, but does not inherently rule out vectorization.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah I misunderstood you, and learned something new that indexing is cheaper :-) I'll give it a try.

Comment: @harold Unfortunately I don't think it is. In there, some data structures are updated that keep track of various "motion groups" (clusters of connected pixels that changed compared to the previous frame). Good to note is that we also require the pixel index (i + j) in that section.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Does it often happen that the test is false for all 8 pixels in a group? Using some SIMD comparisons and mask extracting, it would be easy to fairly efficiently skip the entire loop if all conditions are false

Comment: Byte lookups are inconvenient for a table that large (256 entries) without AVX-512VBMI for `vpermb` or `vpermt2b` (128-byte table parallel lookup, which you could use twice with merge-masking).  Without that, maybe SIMD gathers and either widening the inputs or packing the gather result.  Unless you can have `noiseLevels` expanded to a value per pixel position, instead of indexing on pixel *value* from the previous frame.  That would cost more memory bandwidth and cache footprint, but would allow the whole thing to be SIMD (and enable fast a early-out like harold is suggesting.)

Comment: Here is an example: suppose I want to write three values to a buffer. Version a: `buf[i++] = 0; buf[i++] = 1; buf[i++] = 2;` and version b: `buf[i] = 0; buf[i+1] = 1; buf[i+2] = 2; i += 3;`. Compare the number of memory writes. The indexing can be taken care of with the (x86) compiler, with an offset as part of the instruction.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Compilers will sort out that simplified case on their own, but yes agreed for the OP's case.  It's the conditionals that I'd worry about; a compiler might miss that they all end up the same regardless of how the branching went.  (And it would be much more readable for humans, too; I was scratching my head for a while until I saw that it was really just looping the pointers over 4-byte pixels, no actual data-dependent pointer updates.)  It's not memory writes that differ, though:  `i` would be kept in a register, even with the conditionals. https://godbolt.org/z/jqoqEP9ET

Comment: @PeterCordes in one edited comment I mentioned that the code seems obfuscated. I scratched my head at first too.

Comment: @WeatherVane I updated the original code with your suggestion, see the amendment of the question. I hope that that is what you ment?

Comment: @harold This happens more often than not, yes. Usually the majority (if not the entire) frame is unchanged.

Comment: No, because you had post-increment, so the base index should be `[0]`. And the final addition should be `3` not `4`.

Comment: @ImJustACowLol if it's sparse enough, it may even make sense to use a sparse loop based on the comparison mask: using count-trailing-zeroes to get the index of the first pixel that passes the test, then updating the mask with `mask & (mask - 1)`

Comment: Another inefficiency is the type for `char isDifferent = 0;` which is better as `int.` Don't make the compiler do extra work converting to and from its natural register size. (Why not `bool`? I've never quite understood why is was introduced to C, and I never use it.)

Comment: Your `||` conditionals could maybe be optimized to non-short-circuit `|`.  The compiler might be unwilling to invent an access to `noiseLevels[i]` the abstract machine didn't do, especially if it's a pointer, not a true array.  e.g. the compiler has to make code that's safe even if only the first 128 bytes are safe to access, and the first compare stays within that range and is always true.

Comment: Taking this further, instead of asking it to materialize a boolean, `unsigned char` (`uint8_t`) widened to 32-bit will give you the compare result in the sign bit after subtraction, so you can OR those together.  Like `int signbits = (absdiff[0] - noise0) | (absdiff[1] - noise1) | ...;` `bool isdiff = signbits < 0;`  Should avoid a bunch of `setcc` to materialize a boolean into an 8-bit register before ORing it, at the cost of forcing both loads to use `movzx` instead of an 8-bit memory-source cmp or sub.  So maybe close to break-even, but check the asm.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think you missed the `// Skip alpha` increments before the `if()`.  They have 4-byte ARGB pixels.  This just goes to show how unreadable the original code was for humans!  Also, `char` isn't a performance problem; it's only used locally so compilers have no problem using a whole register for it.  But yeah, for clarity it should be `bool` or `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The indices should be 1, 2 and 3 because the alpha channel (which is at index 0) is skipped ;-)

I've rewritten it to use `bool` as well now.

Comment: I also updated the code so it now contains `bool` in the original post.

Thanks all for the interesting angles on this question, still sifting through all the comments.

Comment: I had a look at `||` vs. `|`, and also "optimizing" `>` into `-` and checking the sign bits of the OR result.  https://godbolt.org/z/WE555x6sY   Using `>` with `|` uses one less branch with GCC, using some `setcc`, at least on its own not inside a loop.  `a-b | c-d | ...` makes branchless asm, but does indeed cost more instructions, so more front-end uops on x86 since the cmp/jcc.  (RISC ISAs would have to load separately anyway, but x86 `cmp mem, reg` can micro-fuse into a load+ALU uop.  And when the next instruction is a JCC, also macro-fuse into a load+compare+branch uop for the front-end.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried to follow up on your suggestion but I could not get it to work thus far:
`int signBits = (absoluteDiff[1] - noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]]) | (absoluteDiff[2] - noiseLevels[previousFrame[2]]) | (absoluteDiff[3] - noiseLevels[previousFrame[3]]);`

Do I need to change something to absoluteDiff/noiseLevels prior to this statement?

Comment: ahh @PeterCordes, following your example, this would be the correct statement: `char signBits = (noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]] - absoluteDiff[1]) | (noiseLevels[previousFrame[2]] - absoluteDiff[2]) | (noiseLevels[previousFrame[3]] - absoluteDiff[3]);`

Comment: @PeterCordes Using the signBits approach I did not see a measurable difference when using llvm-clang + -O3 flag during compilation. However, when using -O0, your suggestion is definitely more performant compared to creating a normal boolean. In a benchmark that uses this code, I saw a 25% performance improvement using signBits. nice one :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes isn't r/w of a `char` more expensive for the processor than `int`? As well as the integer promotions used by C.

Comment: @ImJustACowLol: Benchmarking at `-O0` is meaningless.  Maybe clang's already making branchless asm in your actual loop. re: correctness, I was about to say I might got have the comparisons backwards, either inverting the final boolean condition (`isdiff = !(signbits<0)`), and/or `noise - abs` instead of `abs - noise`. Making both changes introduces an off-by-one, making it possible to do `>` or `>=` this way. e.g. `noise - abs` is non-negative when they're `==` or when `noise > abs` i.e. `abs < noise`.  So checking the sign bit the right way, `abs <= noise` or `!(abs <= noise)` = `abs > noise`

Comment: @WeatherVane: In memory?  Not on x86, although that's irrelevant here for a local with a short lifetime.   In a register, it can take extra work to truncate to 8-bit if necessary, but that's not needed here, compilers will just keep the `char` in a whole 32 or 64-bit register when it's a local variable that's only ever assigned 0 or 1.  If it exists at all except as a `FLAGS` condition.  That's why `bool` variables aren't a disaster for performance, compilers know not to introduce partial-register stalls when using them, and usually avoid false dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to test without knowing what "Do some stuff" is, but here are a couple of potential improvements that jumped out at to me:

1. Replace your array indexing with `gather` instructions

```
// This is mostly pseudocode - don't just copy and paste!
// loop 4 times (2 pixels per iteration)
__m128i diff_expanded = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(*absoluteDiff);
__m128i indices = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(*previousFrame);

__m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi64(0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF);

// This assumes noiseLevels should be an int[] to avoid misaligned loads. 
// You should test both - change last param for size
__m256i thresholds = mm256_mask_i32gather_epi32(noiseLevels, indices, mask, 4); 
__m256i thresh_diff = _mm256_sub_epi32(thresholds, diff_expanded);

// movemask creates a bitmask of the high bits of the packed integers.
int different_px = _mm256_movemask_epi8(thresh_diff_masked) & 0x08000800;

// Do some things if different_px is nonzero
```

2. Like above, but do it all without the need for a loop - the challenge here would be working out my made-up instruction. I suspect the best way to do it would be 4 calls to gather_epi32 -> shuffle -> blendv. Don't try to implement this, instead use the implementations further down.

```
// Again, this is pseudocode
// would need to loop zero times
__m256i indices = *previousFrame;

// in code without my imaginary instruction, this may be a __m128i
__m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi64(0x00FFFFFF00FFFFFF);

// This instruction doesn't exist - but it can be mimicked with the epi32 
// version and some shuffles, mm_unpack instructions, or blendv instructions, 
// but there might also be better ways that I don't know about.
//
// I might come back and edit this answer if I can be more precise here
__m256i thresholds = mm256_mask_i32gather_epi8(noiseLevels, indices, mask, 1); 

// We would like to use _mm256_cmpgt_epu8, but that doesn't exist,
// instead we can use the solution offered here:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234695
__m256i thresh_diff = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(
        _mm_xor_epi8(*absoluteDiff, _mm_set1_epi8(-128)),
        _mm_xor_epi8(thresholds, _mm_set1_epi8(-128)));

uint different_px = _mm256_movemask_epi8(thresh_diff_masked) & 0x77777777;

// Do some things if different_px is nonzero
```

These aren't definitive, but they should hopefully give you a jumping off point for better Avx2 utilization.

Edit: incorporating @PeterCords's recommendations:

```
// This is still pseudocode
// would need to loop zero times per vector

  __m256i absoluteDiff = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_subs_epu8(previousChunk, currentChunk), _mm256_subs_epu8(currentChunk, previousChunk));

// using 4 so we're assuming noiseLevels is an array of dwords with 
// the 3 high bytes zeroed
__m256i indices = *previousFrame;

__m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi32(0x000000FF);

// red channel
__m256i indices_0 = _mm256_and_si256(indices, mask);
__m256i diff_0 = _mm256_and_si256(absoluteDiff, mask);
__m256i threshold_0 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(noiseLevels, indices_0, 4);
__m256i cmp_0 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(diff_0 , threshold_0);

// blue channel
__m256i indices_1 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi32(indices, 8), mask);
__m256i diff_1 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi32(absoluteDiff, 8), mask);
__m256i threshold_1 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(noiseLevels, indices_1, 4);
__m256i cmp_1 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(diff_1 , threshold_1);


// green channel
__m256i indices_2 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi32(indices, 16), mask);
__m256i diff_2 = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi32(absoluteDiff, 16), mask);
__m256i threshold_2 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(noiseLevels, indices_2, 4);
__m256i cmp_2 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(diff_2 , threshold_2);

// from here you'd want to test cmp_0, cmp_1, and cmp_2
// you can OR them all together if you don't care about which pixel
// and then apply movemask or do movemask on each (which would likely
// be slower)
```

It would also be worth testing if modifying `indices` and `absoluteDiff` would be faster:

```
// This is still pseudocode
// I'm assuming you care about which specific pixel is selected.
// This uses more slower instructions, but it should need fewer
// cache references

  __m256i absoluteDiff = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_subs_epu8(previousChunk, currentChunk), _mm256_subs_epu8(currentChunk, previousChunk));

// using 4 so we're assuming noiseLevels is an array of dwords with 
// the 3 high bytes zeroed
//
// You could also use _mm256_sll_epi32  which has higher latency but
// better throughput but you would have to pass it a m128i shift count
__m256i indices = *previousFrame;

__m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi32(0x000000FF);

// red channel
__m256i indices_0 = _mm256_and_si256(indices, mask);
__m256i diff_0 = _mm256_and_si256(absoluteDiff, mask);
__m256i threshold_0 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(noiseLevels, indices_0, 4);
__m256i cmp_0 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(diff_0, threshold_0);

uint res = _mm256_movemask_ps(cmp_0);

// blue channel
indices = _mm256_srli_epi32(indices, 8);
absoluteDiff = _mm256_srli_epi32(absoluteDiff, 8);
__m256i indices_1 = _mm256_and_si256(indices, mask);
__m256i diff_1 = _mm256_and_si256(absoluteDiff, mask);
__m256i threshold_1 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(noiseLevels, indices_1, 4);
__m256i cmp_1 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(diff_1, threshold_1);
res |= _mm256_movemask_ps(cmp_1);

// green channel
indices = _mm256_srli_epi32(indices, 8);
absoluteDiff = _mm256_srli_epi32(absoluteDiff, 8);
__m256i indices_2 = _mm256_and_si256(indices, mask);
__m256i diff_2 = _mm256_and_si256(absoluteDiff, mask);
__m256i threshold_2 = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(noiseLevels, indices_2, 4);
__m256i cmp_2 = _mm256_cmpgt_epi32(diff_2, threshold_2);
res |= _mm256_movemask_ps(cmp_2);

// from here, each nonzero bit in the low byte of res represents
// a pixel where one channel exceeded the threshold
```

Comment: On most CPUs (https://uops.info/), a mask that's not all-ones doesn't make `vpgatherdd` faster, and generating an all-ones vector is slightly cheaper than with the high 4 bytes zeroed in each 128-bit lane.  Since the table is only 256 entries, garbage in the low element is probably not touching any new cache lines so it might be better to do an unmasked gather (which the compiler internally needs to generate an all-ones mask for).  Especially if the alpha difference is usually or always 0. You still need to mask the `movemask` result after compare.

Comment: Instead of `vpmovzxbd` which results in doing 4 gathers per 32 bytes of input, we could `vpsrd` / `vpand` (or `vpshufb`; clang optimizes shift+mask into `vpshufb` for us) to isolate one of the 3 bytes we care about at the bottom of a dword, for a dword gather.  Then we can skip the alpha channel.  The gathers could be unaligned 4-byte loads where we only care about the low bit, perhaps with an offset for the base address which puts the byte we want into position to just blend.

Comment: (`vpblendvb` is 2 uops for any port on Intel, or 3 uops on Alder Lake.  But recombining data at the bottom of each dword also takes a shift / OR if it's zero-extended, or worse if it was a dword gather on packed bytes pulling in upper garbage.  dword gathers on a dword LUT avoids cache-line split loads, so that's definitely competitive if the cache footprint isn't a problem.)

Comment: With bytes zero-extended into dwords, packing pairs in a single instruction could be done with an FP FMA; the bit-pattern is a subnormal since no bits are set outside the low 23, the mantissa.  But presumably that takes a slow microcode assist, otherwise we could use that to shift left by 8 (multiply by 256.0) and add, since x86 doesn't have integer MAC or shift|OR single instruction like ARM NEON's shift-and-insert.  (`pmaddwd` can be useful for combining pairs horizontally within the same vector, trading latency against being a single uop for throughput.)

Comment: There is no `_mm256_subs_epi32` (only byte and word saturating subtracts).  But you don't want that anyway: since you have bytes zero-extended to 32-bit, they're non-negative integers you can compare with `_mm256_cmpgt_epi32`.  The saturating subtract in this problem is part of generating `absoluteDiff`, and should still be done in 8-bit before widening.   Also, if you want you could use `_mm256_movemask_ps` to pack the mask results to 1 bit per element.

Comment: I'll take a look at implementing these suggestions and trying to understand them as well. I'm still new to AVX/programming with intrinsics (this is quite literally my first project) so it'll take some time :-)

Comment: I noticed that `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32` is compiler-specific. Is there an equivalent in AVX2? I'm digging through Intel's documentation at the moment but can only find expand for AVX512

Comment: `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32 ` is the instruction `pmovzxbd` and a part of SSE4.1 ([Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_cvtepu8_epi32%25252520&ig_expand=1881)). The 256 bit version is in Avx2.

Comment: `_mm256_subs_epu8` (unsigned saturation) exists (contrary to the comments in your code), but you can't use the MSB of any 8-bit subtraction as a compare: you need the 9th bit, the carry-out, unless the inputs are known to be within 127 of each other.  What doesn't exist (until AVX-512) is unsigned integer *compare*, so you should emulate it by range-shifting your inputs to signed by flipping their MSBs (with xor with `_mm256_set1_epi8(0x80)`) so you can use `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8`

Comment: Your comments mention `_mm256_sll_epi32` and a `__m128i` shift count.  You're looking for `_mm256_slli_epi32`, taking an immediate shift count.  See https://godbolt.org/z/6c9sxennh for an example of shifting each byte of a dword to the bottom to do something with them, and how clang optimizes `_mm256_and_si256( _mm256_srli_epi32(v, 24), set1(0x000000ff))` into a `vpshufb`.  (From a pangram-checking function I was playing around with, turning a char into a set bit in a bitmap.  That part is unrelated to this problem, but processing each byte in a dword separately is the same problem).

Comment: @gfaster I'm still trying to understand the latest edit to your answer (takes some time for me as I'm not well versed in AVX2). Am I correct to say that the solution still requires both noiseLevels and indices to have been expanded from `char` to `int32`? And also that I need to compute a cmp_3 as well, because I assume each cmp contains the results for only 2 pixels?

Comment: @ImJustACowLol yes, your assessment is correct there on the expansion of noiseLevels to u32, however indices is still char (we mask the relevant bytes to isolate int32s). The reason we do that is because we can't gather single bytes - at minimum it's dwords. On the second one, each gather and cmp is one channel: cmp_0 is r, cmp_1 is g, cmp_2 is b. You don't need a cmp_3 unless you're also comparing the alpha channel.

Comment: @PeterCordes The reason I mentioned `_mm256_sll_epi32` was the supposedly higher throughput than `_mm256_slli_epi32` according to version 3.6.6 of the Intel Intrinsics guide. However, given the compiler optimizations, I don't think it was worth bringing up.

Comment: The intrinsics guide gives costs in reciprocal throughput, effective cycles per instruction.  So 1 per 0.5 cycles means it can do 2/clock `vpslld ymm, ymm, imm8` vs. 1/clock `vpslld ymm, ymm, xmm`.  You can see the same thing on https://uops.info/ or https://agner.org/optimize/, which also provide details on number of uops (front-end throughput) and which ports they can run on (so you can work out bottlenecks for mixes of different instructions that might or might not compete for the same port).

Comment: With the count in an XMM register, it costs an extra port-5 uop.  On Skylake and later, presumably to broadcast the count for a `vpsllvd` uop (which can run on either of port 0 or 1, same as immediate shifts).  On Haswell and earlier, presumably some other implementation technique but it's still an extra uop.  Anyway, `_mm256_sll_epi32` is worse throughput than `_mm256_slli_epi32`.

Comment: One of your edits changed to the non-existent `_mm256_cmpgt_epu8` after I  commented with a way to emulate it using AVX2 with `_mm256_xor_si256` on both inputs as in [SSE Compare Packed Unsigned Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16204663), so I'd recommend doing that for an AVX2 answer.  Even with AVX-512, `_mm256_cmpgt_epu8` doesn't exist, only `_mm256_cmpgt_epu8_mask` which produces a `__mmask8`, not `__m256i`.

Comment: Oh no I've been reading the intrinsics wrong my whole life :( - I know it was CPI but I never put 2 and 2 together that it's inverse. I'll also update the answer to note the `_mm256_cmpgt_epu8` workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @gfaster I got your example working (example nr 3). I misunderstood it at first, thinking that cmp_0...cmp_2 were clusters of pixels rather than color channels.

Unfortunately it is not yet faster than the implementation I have in my question with the feedback processed from other comments. I suspect the clang compiler is doing some optimizations that we're missing at the moment. Still reading into how I can make it faster as well.

Comment: The difference compared to the implementation in my answer is roughly 36% longer execution time. For compilation I'm using clang llvm with the flags:
`-O3 -ffast-math -mavx -mavx2`

I did end up combining cmp_0...cmp_2 by doing: `__m256i combinedComp = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_or_si256(cmp_0, cmp_1), cmp_2);`.

This allows me to only use a single `if` per pixel.

Comment: At this point, you should be running `perf` or similar to figure out where your bottlenecks are. You might also want to try either making the inside of your `if` statement branch-less SIMD if most pixels are branching or extracting it to it's own function for cache coherence if very few pixels branch. You could also do one test if the vector is nonzero before checking individual pixels.

Comment: @gfaster I will look into running perf. I will admit i'm very much a rookie at C, especially compared to you and PeterCordes. But I did learn a lot about AVX2 with these discussions. Just want to let you and Peter know I very much appreciate your input and the learnings I got up until this point.

I also updated my original question with a new optimization I found; determining for 8-pixel chunks of anything of interest happened and if not then continuing early to the next chunk of 8 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of optimizing and incoorporating some ideas/suggestions of @PeterCordes and @gfaster, I came to the algorithm below. One significant change in this algorithm is that **the alpha channel is no longer ignored**. Even though the alpha channel is not interesting for the comparison (as it's always expected to be 255), I found that I was able to write the most efficient algorithm by comparing it anyway.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i += 8) {
  __m256i previousChunk = _mm256_loadu_si256(previousFrame);
  __m256i currentChunk = _mm256_loadu_si256(currentFrame);
  __m256i absoluteDiff = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_subs_epu8(previousChunk, currentChunk), _mm256_subs_epu8(currentChunk, previousChunk));
  __m256i noiseLevelsChunk = _mm256_set_epi8(
    -1, // Alpha channel can be ignored for comparison. Set every noiseLevel that corresponds to a alpha channel to 255 (or -1 signed).
    noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]],
    ...
    noiseLevels[previousFrame[30]],
    noiseLevels[previousFrame[31]]
  );
  __m256i comparedChunk = _mm256_subs_epu8(absoluteDiff, noiseLevelsChunk);
  int comparisonMask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpgt_epi8(comparedChunk, _mm256_setzero_si256()));

  if (!comparisonMask) {
    previousFrame += 32;
    currentFrame += 32;
    continue;
  }

  int* pixelComparisons = (int*) &comparedChunk;
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if (pixelComparisons[j]) {
      // Do stuff
    }
  }

  currentFrame += 32;
  previousFrame += 32;
}
```

This incoorporates the following optimizations as compared to the original question:

**Using `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8` to compare absoluteDiff against noiseLevels**

I tried many ways of doing the comparison between the absolute diff and the noise levels through AVX2, including the usage of `gather` operations to gather the noise levels for memory. However, for all approaches attempted, performance suffered. In the end, using `_mm256_set_epi8` to set all the noise levels into a YMM register yielded by far the best performance. Some speculation: I suspect the reason is that the relevant contents of `previousFrame` are still stored on the processor's cache (as `previousFrame` has been accessed a few lines earlier to load it into a YMM register) and as a result it is readily available when looking up the noise levels.

Then, by subtracting the noise level from the diff and then checking for which pixels this new value is non-zero, it can be determined if a pixel changed significantly. Using this method, the algorithm compares 8 pixels at a time, yielding a significant performance boost relative to comparing every pixel's color components individually.

**Early return by creating a 32-bit mask**

Creating a mask of the most significant bits per byte in `comparedChunk`, allows to very quickly skip chunks of 8 pixels in which nothing significant changed:

```c
  int comparisonMask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpgt_epi8(comparedChunk, _mm256_setzero_si256()));
if (!comparisonMask) {
  previousFrame += 32;
  currentFrame += 32;
}
```

A sidenote here is that using this specific optimization is only helpful if it is expected to happen often that clusters of pixels did not change significantly. Comparing frames with strong variance (e.g. due to strong noise) may not benefit from this optimization.

---

---

**Edit 2023-06-13 19:39 amsterdam time**

As pointed out by @PeterCordes, the way in which I computed `comparedChunk` would only work if both the noise levels and diff are <= 127u. As the algorithm should support the full unsigned byte range (0-255), I updated this answer with the fix as proposed by PeterCordes.

The old (*wrong*) way the value was computed was: `__m256i comparedChunk = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(absoluteDiff, noiseLevelsChunk);`

**Edit 2023-07-08 17:45 Amsterdam time**

I found a new optimization that changes how the `comparisonMask` is calculated. The new implementation has been updated in the answer. Performance increase is roughly 12% for my machine. The old implementation (see below) required to XOR the diff and the noise levels as `cmpgt` only works on signed bytes. This introduced some overhead which is avoided with the new approach.

The old implementation:

```c
  __m256i xorMask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x80);
  __m256i comparedChunk = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_xor_si256(absoluteDiff, xorMask), _mm256_xor_si256(noiseLevelsChunk, xorMask));
  int comparisonMask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(comparedChunk);
```

**Edit 2023-07-10 19:02**

As the alpha channel may be ignored, one can skip loading the noise levels for the alpha channel into `noiseLevelsChunk`. This optimization prevents a lot of unneeded memory access, yielding a few percent performance increase.

The old way of loading the `noiseLevelsChunk` was this:

```c
  __m256i noiseLevelsChunk = _mm256_set_epi8(
    noiseLevels[previousFrame[0]],
    noiseLevels[previousFrame[1]],
    ...
    noiseLevels[previousFrame[30]],
    noiseLevels[previousFrame[31]]
  );
```

Comment: `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8` is a signed compare.  You have 8-bit unsigned differences.  Is it safe to assume they and the noise levels are always `<= 127u`?  I'd have thought not, like a change from black to white could certain happen in one frame for most videos.  Maybe OR in the absolute difference after the compare so the MSB is set if the absdiff was huge, on the assumption that the noise level is always less than 128.  Or just do it right and XOR both with `set1_epi8(0x80)` ahead of `cmpgt`, or `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8( b, _mm256_max_epu8(a,b))` to do an unsigned `>=` compare.

Comment: The absolute difference of two 8-bit inputs is a `uint8_t` with value-range of 0-255, not a signed `int8_t` with value-range -128 .. +127.  `epi8` intrinsics treat the 8-bit bit-pattern as representing a value in the range -128 .. +127.  i.e. it's a signed compare.  It would say that `200 < 100` because 200 (0xc8) is actually `-56` when interpreted as an 8-bit 2's complement signed integer, like `pcmpgtb` does.  That's what "signed compare" means.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah I missed the fact that it is a signed compare... Good catch. I'll take your suggestions and see what works best.

Also removed my other comment as I misread what you wrote ;)

Comment: @PeterCordes After doing some testing, i ended up with finding that including the XOR as well gives a minimal performance penalty while fixing the computation. Thanks for the headsup :) I'll update my answer